# Excel CountIF on date AND time

Tags: excel, datetime, sumifs

I see lots of examples of how to work with times **OR** dates, but not a lot seems to be done with date **AND** time values.

I have the following data:

[image: Data e.g.]

And would like the sum of some weights between specific date and times (shift patterns):

So

1. I need all the weights between "17/07/2014 06:00" and "17/07/2014 14:00"
2. I need all the weights between "17/07/2014 14:00" and "17/07/2014 22:00"
3. I need all the weights between "17/07/2014 22:00" and "**18**/07/2014 06:00"

Yes, I can split the dates and times and deal with them separately, but there must be an easier way (it gets rather convoluted in the 3rd scenario)

By the way, the date to compare against will be calculated using "=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW())-1)" for yesterdays date (stored in F11)

I have an entire page of different variations of attempts at this, which I wont post all of, but mainly:

```
 =SUMIFS(
   Last36Hours!$K$2:$K$10000,
   Last36Hours!$T$2:$T$10000,">=" & 
      DATE(YEAR(F11),MONTH(F11),DAY(F11)) & 
      TIME(6,0,0)
 )
```

should give me everything after yesterday 6am, but i get absolutely squat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Close. Excel stores dates and times as days and fractions of days since 1/1/1900 or 1/1/1904. You need to **ADD** the time to the date, not concatenate.  And you can simplify getting the Date portion from F11. Try:

```
=SUMIFS(
   Last36Hours!$K$2:$K$10000,
   Last36Hours!$T$2:$T$10000,">=" &
     INT(F11)+ TIME(6,0,0))
```

You could also hard code yesterday at 6AM by replacing

```
DATE(YEAR(F11),MONTH(F11),DAY(F11)) & TIME(6,0,0)
```

with

```
TODAY()-0.75
```

which is the same as:

```
TODAY() - 1 + TIME(6,0,0)
```

Comment: This looks promising, however its still not working. I suspect a data format issue perhaps. My source column is custom formatted "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" and is an output from an SQL query (stored as string). Is there a way to "cast" the items in the range to force datetime format? Should I even need to?

Comment: I've tried "=COUNTIF(Last36Hours!$Q$2:$Q$10000,">=" & TODAY() -0.75)" to no avail

Comment: And before anyone asks, the range is correct (the earlier ones weren't but good enough for demonstration)

Comment: @user1830285 Is the data in column T truly a date/time?  If it is, =isnumber(T3) should --> TRUE.

Comment: It returned false, yet the cell format is definitely custom "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm". I also tried changing the cell format to number and it still returned false. Ill go back to my SQL

Comment: @user1830285 Since it ISTEXT, Excel will not see it as a date (and changing the cell numberformat will not change that).  What are your Windows regional settings (in Control Panel)?  They need to be the same as the format coming from your SQL.  If they are not the same, you should change one or the other.

Comment: Once I forced date/time format in the SQL query, this started working. Thanks for your assistance.